# complex layout using react storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am new to react storybook and have created relatively simple stories so far as mentioned below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';

export default {
  title: "Test"
}

export const test = () => <textarea onClick={action('textarea clicked')}>Hong test from me</textarea>;
export const input = () => <input type="text"></input>;
```

With this knowledge, I want to go ahead and create complex stories i.e. as shown in the image below:

[image]

Is there any tutorial which will help me achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: how do we add css grids, does react-storybook already has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I will try to give you an answer. 
What we usually do with storybook stories is to create the story and then import a complex component inside it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { CustomComponent } from '../src';

storiesOf('CustomComponent', module)
      .add('Custom Component story 1', () => (
        <CustomComponent />
  ));
```